# Using a unique div Id in php passed to javascript and used to run another php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a div that uses some unique id from a mysql db that I have to pass to my javascript file so I could display results from another php script in a particular div with a specific id that corresponds to the one obtained from the db.

index page.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<?php 
    $query = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM in_table limit 10 ');

    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
        <img src= <?php echo $result['user_image_url']; ?> />

    <?php 
        echo $result['msg'].'</br>';
        echo '<a href="#'.$result['statusID'].'">More...</a></br>';

        echo '<div id="'.$result['statusID'].'" class="rest" style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>';
    }
?>
```

The div is inside the while loop.

ajax.js

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    var hash = this.hash.replace('#','');

    $.post('content.php', {id: hash}, function(data){
        $('div#?????').html(data);
    });

})
```

So how do I call that div inside?

content.php

```
<?php
    include('ajax.php');

    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
    }

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM comments where statusID = '".$id."'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        echo $row['message'].'</br>';
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the hash in the selector?

```
$.post('content.php', {id: hash}, function(data){
    $('div#' + hash).html(data);
});
```

I also heard its more lightweight and more intentionally correct to use GET when retrieving something and using POST when modifying something.

---

## Edit:

You said you were using all integers as IDs, which is bad for DOM. Try putting some text before the IDs like so:

```
echo '<a href="#t'.$result['statusID'].'">More...</a></br>';
echo '<div id="t'.$result['statusID'].'" class="rest" style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>';
```

Now the ID will be something like `t1000` and **NOT** `1000`.

Then in your JS do

```
$.post('content.php', {id: hash}, function(data){
    $('div#t' + hash).html(data);
});
```

Comment: What is your `statusID` like? Are they all integers perhaps?

Comment: Yes. they are all integers

Comment: I have tried that too but there is no difference so far. And then, introducing the 't' changes the statusID which has to be used in the content.php file to search the db.

Answer (score 0):

I think voldomazta's answer will also work. There is another way you can do this. Modify your anchor tag to include a data attribute:

```
echo '<a href="#'.$result['statusID'].'" data-id="'.$result['statusID'].'">More...</a></br>';
```

and you can use this in jQuery

```
$.post('content.php', {id: hash}, function(data){
        $('div#'+$(this).data('id)).html(data);
    });
```

If you are not aware of data attributes, they can be used flexibly defining your own attributes as data-xyz="" in HTML tags and use them in jQuery as $(...).data('xyz')

Comment: hi nitigyan, the scope of `this` inside the callback function of the ajax call is not in the click event, so `this` will be a reference to the window and not the anchor tag.

Comment: Yes, voldomazta my bad! not sure what I was thinking, just being over worked I guess :(